# Make cshell script wait until LSF job finish

Tags: shell, lsf

I have a shell script which submit the task to LSF server, and not until the job is finished, certain sets of commands will be performed over the output files. But since I put the task into bsub, the task gets executed on other server, if I put the commands in the later part of the very same script, that sets of command would be executed immediately. May I know is there a way to monitor the finish of the task so that I can run the remaining part of the script? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can poll `bjobs -o`, or if you have a newer version of LSF, use `bwait`.